# In python, how do I find the positions of a word that occurs more than once in a sentence using a for loop?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, for-loop, substring

Basically, i need to make a python 2.7 program where the user inputs a sentence, then inputs a word, and if the word is in the sentence, the program displays its position(s). if the word is not in the sentence, the program needs to outputs an error message saying something like "the word is not in the sentence". The sentence and the word must not be case sensitive and the program has to use a for loop. My attempt at it is just terrible but here's what i tried:

```
sentence = raw_input("enter your sentence: ")

word = raw_input("enter word: ")

len(sentence)

for i in range(int(sentence)):

    print sentence.find(word)
```

The output of my code:

```
enter your sentence: hello bob my name is bob too
enter word: bob

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GCSE Python\CPCA- Task 1 Code.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in range(int(s1)):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello bob im bob too'
>>>
```

Comment: Your code and your input does not match your error.

Comment: The error message you are getting is because you are doing `int(sentence)`. I think you meant to get the length, which means you want `len(sentence)`. But that only covers the error you are getting. Beyond that, there are other issues. But someone just answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
>>> s='hello bob my name is bob too'
>>> ss='bob'
>>> [i for i in range(len(s)) if s.startswith(ss, i)]
[6, 21]
```

Or, as a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s.startswith(ss, i):
        print i
```

Or, slightly better, because you do not create a useless `range` list in Python 2:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(s):
    if s.startswith(ss, i):
        print i
```